Downloading File from Sonatype Nexus and Uploading it to SFTP server using Jenkins Pipeline
Hello,
I have some files that I want to download from Sonatype Nexus repo and upload it to my SFTP server using a Jenkins pipeline. The repo and the server are all running internally (on the local network).
My Jenkins is running inside a Docker container. Below is my current pipeline script.
    stage('Pull the file off Nexus') {
        withCredentials([usernameColonPassword(credentialsId: 'REDACTED ID', variable: 'NEXUS_CREDENTIALS')]) {
            sh script: '''
            curl -u ${NEXUS_CREDENTIALS} -o maven-metadata.xml "PATH TO FILE in NEXUS"
            '''
        }
    }
stage('Upload file(s) to server') {
            withCredentials([usernameColonPassword(credentialsId: 'REDACTED ID', variable: 'FTP_CREDENTIALS')]) {
            sh script: '''
            # Extract username and password from FTP_CREDENTIALS
            USERNAME=$(echo ${FTP_CREDENTIALS} | cut -d: -f1)
            PASSWORD=$(echo ${FTP_CREDENTIALS} | cut -d: -f2)
            SERVER=IP_ADDRESS
            REMOTE_DIR=/home/peter/deploy/
            FILE=maven-metadata.xml

            # Print extracted values for debugging
            echo "USERNAME=${USERNAME}"
            echo "PASSWORD=${PASSWORD}"
            
            # Use sftp with a batch mode
            echo "Uploading $FILE to $SERVER"
            sftp -oBatchMode=no -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no -oPasswordAuthentication=yes ${USERNAME}@${SERVER} << EOF
            cd $REMOTE_DIR
            put $FILE
            bye
            EOF
            '''
        }

    }
}


Downloading the file from Nexus to Jenkins works as expected but the second portion continues to have an error. Below is the error message:
Started by user admin
[Pipeline] Start of Pipeline
[Pipeline] node
Running on Jenkins in /var/jenkins_home/workspace/nexus_test
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Pull the file off Nexus)
[Pipeline] withCredentials
Masking supported pattern matches of $NEXUS_CREDENTIALS
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] sh
+ curl -u **** -o maven-metadata.xml PATH_TO_FILE_ON_NEXUS
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed

  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
100   284  100   284    0     0  30017      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 31555
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withCredentials
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Upload file(s) to server)
[Pipeline] withCredentials
Masking supported pattern matches of $FTP_CREDENTIALS
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] sh
+ echo ****
+ cut -d: -f1
+ USERNAME=REDACTED
+ echo ****
+ cut -d: -f2
+ PASSWORD=REDACTED
+ SERVER=IP_ADDRESS
+ REMOTE_DIR=/home/peter/deploy/
+ FILE=maven-metadata.xml
+ echo USERNAME=REDACTED
USERNAME=REDACTED
+ echo PASSWORD=REDACTED
PASSWORD=REDACTED
+ echo Uploading maven-metadata.xml to IP_ADDRESS
Uploading maven-metadata.xml to IP_ADDRESS
+ sftp -oBatchMode=no -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no -oPasswordAuthentication=yes REDACTED@IP_ADDRESS
Warning: Permanently added 'IP_ADDRESS' (ED25519) to the list of known hosts.
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied, please try again.
REDACTED@IP_ADDRESS: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password).

Connection closed.  
Connection closed
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withCredentials
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
ERROR: script returned exit code 255
Finished: FAILURE

As this is my first time with shell scripting and working with Jenkins, any help will be appreciated.
Thank you

Check your SFTP folder permission on where you would put the file to make sure it has enough permission to do so.
Consider using scp for shorter command.
